# Existence of canonical retraction around a compact manifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, compact-manifolds

This semester in my differential geometry class the professor stated the following without further comment:

Let $N$ be a compact smooth manifold in $\mathbf{R}^n$. For $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough, there exists a canonical retraction $\rho$ from the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood $U$ of $N$ to $N$, which is a submersion.

I thought that $\rho(x)$ might be defined as the closest point of $N$ to $x$, which is well-defined, as $N$ is compact. Then $\rho$ is a continuous map and thus clearly a retraction onto $N$. But why should $\rho$ be a submersion?

Thanks!

Comment: IMO there are subtleties you are overgoing in your definition of the retractions (they are taken care of by $\epsilon$ small enough). But the map is a submersion, because every path in $N$ is also a path in $U$, as $N$ is included in $U$.

Comment: @Steven: The subtlety in the definition of $\rho$ is to show "There exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that if $x$ is a point of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ with $d(x, N) < \varepsilon$, then there exists a _unique_ $x'$ in $N$ with $d(x, x') = d(x, N)$."

Comment: Have you seen the Tubular Neighborhood Theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is basically correct, but I think things get much easier if you turn things around and start from the normal bundle of $N$. So take $E:=\{(x,v)\in N\times\mathbb R^n:v\perp T_xN\}$ and the map $\phi:E\to\mathbb R^n$ defined by $\phi(x,v):=x+v$. This is immediately seen to have invertible differential in $(x,0)$ for all $x\in N$ and hence is a diffeomorphism locally around each of these points. Compactness of $N$ easily implies that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\phi$ restricts to a diffeomorphism from $W:=\{(x,v)\in E:\|v\|<\epsilon\}$ onto an open neighborhood $U$ of $N$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Then you can define $\rho:U\to N$ as the composition of the first projection $W\to N$ (which clearly is a surjective submersion) with $\phi^{-1}$.